# Displaying paragraphs in HTML

Tags: html, text-formatting

I'm writing a web application which needs to bring the stored paragraphs into the front web. The text come from excel work sheet and contains control characters like indent. I want to show the text in the exactly manner as it was in excel. How can I do that then? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have a hard time converting Office formatting into HTML/CSS, be prepared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your text to begin with, my initial suggestion would be to wrap it in pre-formatted tags. Note that this won't work for formatting like italics, underlines, etc. Merely white-space:

```
<pre>
Anything within these tags will

maintain  its    original formatting. Spaces, new lines, and all.
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you to save your excel file as web page into new file and use the html of this new file in your application.

Comment: Yes, the former solution we use is export the sheet into a html page.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [RTF-to-HTML conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html).