# Render RTF document as an image on the web

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, rtf

I have many RTF documents storend in my database. I'm trying to create a webpage to render an RTF document as an image. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing to a [Virtual Image Printer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageprinter/) and then serve the image it produced.

Answer (score 0):

See this project

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2html/ (Also cf. http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTMLGeneration/rtf2html.html)

Also see this question answered a year ago:

[Convert Rtf to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)

It includes a C# option on codeproject

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is convert RTF to HTML instead of image, because of:

1. Image is a raster and will look different in various monitors
2. Image has more size (kb) than HTML
3. Converting to Image in even case slower than to HTML