# C# converting RTF to html

Tags: c#, .net, html, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Rtf to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)

I'm trying to export text from a C# app to a Flash movie hoping to get the same formatted text. Flash can handle html tags, so my question is: `Is it possible to convert formatted text from a RichTextBox into HTML using C#?`  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, question has already been asked and answered:

[Convert Rtf to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)