# How to Convert RTF Data in HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, rtf

I have saved data in RTF Format in MS Access Database. Which looks like:

{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\deftab720{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\froman\fcharset2 Symbol;}{\f2\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}{\f3\fswiss\fprq2 Arial;}{\f4\froman\fprq2\fcharset2 Symbol;}{\f5\fswiss\fprq2 MS Sans Serif;}} {\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;} \deflang1033\pard\plain\f3\fs20 All India Radio \plain\f2\fs17 \par }

I want to display the data in HTML format.

Is there any free script/tool available for same.

If anyone knows of a software which can convert the entire data in HTML format, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Rtf to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html) or [Converting RTF to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585376/c-converting-rtf-to-html) or [Simple Convert Rtf to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265566/simple-convert-rtf-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

Read this articles

http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/10/20/rtf_5F00_html.aspx

or use these controls:

http://www.subsystems.com/hcw.htm

http://www.shareup.com/RTF-2-HTML-download-29167.html