# Read file from blob url container

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Below is my blob url where my word file is located, and I want to read the file and show its content in my web form(C#).

https://vikranttest.blob.core.windows.net/Vikrantproduction/applicationeulaVikrant/vikky.rtf

Comment: Related to/duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string fileString = client.DownloadString(new uri(http://.....)));
```

Now if you put that string into a rtf box it should keep the formatting.

Comment: thanks Haedrain, but when I am filling this string into text of freetextbox(FreeTextBox.dll) it is not formatted. how do I formate it