# How to convert RTF to HTML

Tags: c++, mfc, ms-office

Could you please tell me if there is a good free C++ class/library to convert RTF to HTML? Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with Microsoft Office?

Comment: What do you mean, convert RTF to HTML?

Comment: @SethCarnegie - RTF is a file format, HTML is a file format... so a class to convert one to the other

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Rtf to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)... if you are using MFC, then C# is not really a stretch

Comment: Have you looked into using wvWare? http://wvware.sourceforge.net

Comment: I'm gonna try http://phvu.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/rtf-to-html-converter-in-c/

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I thought there is a public interface/COM object in Office I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Word Automation (i.e. integrate with Microsoft Office). Then, through the MS Word class, open the RTF, save it as HTML.

1. [Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28v=office.14%29.aspx) rtf file.
2. [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) using WdSaveFormat = [wdFormatHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you! But I was looking for something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2html-lite/