# wanted to show rtf content (i.e which is stored in db) in web application through Javascript/Jquery

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to show rtf content (i.e which is stored in db) in web application through Javascript/Jquery

I tried with telerik control, it works well in server side code but my requirement is client side programming..

Let me know if any suggestions ..

Thanks in Advance 
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting RTF to HTML on the fly and then outputting the HTML see this related post:

[Convert Rtf to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)