# How to find picture in richtext c#?

Tags: c#, .net, find, image

How to find pictures in richtext, is there any method for doing that?

I need to generate html from richtext so i need to find picture and find on which position is.

This is code which i use to put picture in richtext

```
        Clipboard cl;            
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("c:\\time.png");
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(myBitmap);
        Clipboard.SetImage(myBitmap);         
        rchBody.Paste();
```

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Show your effort here.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Can you outline this with some code? It's not clear what you mean by "rich text", there's at least two `RichTextBox` controls in .NET - the WinForms one and the XAML one - and a whole lot of other code that deals with "rich text". (And I believe both of them produce fairly opaque content that's not really suitable for processing, but I'm not so sure about that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly the same, have you looked at this other SO question? [Convert Rtf to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html) .

The answer points you to this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

There you can get a lot of details on how to do it, including RTF with images.