# C# Is that possible to Convert byte containing .rtf document to byte containing pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, rtf

I'm trying to send Email where content is a rtf document in database (column BLOB).

So, I get my document in byte type from my DB, but then I don't know how to convert the rtf content into a readable text for an Email.

```
byte[] text = itm.Doc;

body= "<html><body>";

using (var file = new MemoryStream(text))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        body+= reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But this of course, give me a rtf text, as the actual content of 'byte[] text'.

Can I convert my byte, containing rtf, to a byte containg pdf?

Thank you.

Comment: What about `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` as below?

Comment: It is the same result.

Comment: One more suggest: try `string[] lines = rtBox.Lines`.

Comment: Instead of the 'string plainText = rtBox.Text;'? I have juste 'System.String[]' in the mail...

Comment: Yes. Then add to mail.Body.

Comment: `mail.Body = "<html><body>" + string.Join("<br/>", lines) + "</body></html>";`

Comment: No good result either. I think I must change Encoding of text, and then enter in my loop.

Comment: Check this question also. May be it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html.

Comment: @Zaphod did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the same thing, rtf as oracle blob to pdf. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the guide to convert rtf to plain text:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc488002.aspx

Update:
Try `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` like this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
  reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  body += reader.ReadToEnd();
}

rtBox.Rtf = body;
string[] lines = rtBox.Lines;

mail.Body = "<html><body>" + string.Join("<br/>", lines) + "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Here, you got a local file. I have a rtf file, store as blob in DB, and as a byte[] into my code. That is different or i'm totally blind.

Comment: `string rtfText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)` from sample is analogous to your `body += reader.ReadLine()`, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Indeed, but the text doesn't have the lineBreak, it is just the full text without spaces... Edit first post.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov: That is not analogous. `ReadLine` swallows the newline.