# Send RTF in a HTML body by email C#

Tags: c#, html, email, rtf

We have an C# application which sends emails to clients. In these emails can be information about several things and this information can contains a note.

Example email:

Person: John
  Age: 35
  Note: He works as developer.
        (Jonn's picture)
        (Excel table)

Person: Mary
  Age: 40
  Note: (Another picture)
        bla bla bla

Until now, we extracted the plain text of  the note, but now we want to send the whole note (it is written in rtf format and it can contain images, excel tables and so on).

The email body is made in HTML and can contain several notes.

Does someone know what will be the best option to add these notes to the email? Is it that possible? because the body is a HTML document and I have to add several notes... Maybe is it easier as image (try to get an image from the rtf)? or is it better in HTML?

I hope you can help me or guide me.
Thank you in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rtf to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely its possible. I did similar sort of thing. First read RTF contents into a string (say rtfContent) by using InputStreamReader, then pass this string to a method ConvertRtf2Html(rtfContent). You can follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) to download the project which converts RTF content to HTML and much(I don't know all the functionality, as I used only ConvertRtf2Html() method)