# Convert rtf to html in winforms

Tags: winforms

I have a richtextbox in windows form . I want to send the data inside the richtextbox in mail body. Richtextbox.text not gives the formatting, so i used richtextbox.rtf. But it is showing rtf codes. How to convert rtf to html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Rtf to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from [Writing Your Own RTF Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) where the author have described on how to write a custom RTF parser and converter.

Also, this MSDN post will sound helpful

[Convert RichTextBox text to html](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cda6e8a4-0834-41ef-996f-1618bd652afe/convert-richtextbox-text-to-html?forum=Vsexpressvb)

Ahh!! this post looks like a duplicate of [Convert Rtf to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html)

Comment: I got the solution  from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265566/simple-convert-rtf-to-html  But the images are converted to wmf format and not showing in browser