# Is it possible to Format Underline in RTF C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have RTF box in my form. In the message i bolded selected words and changed color as well.

I've a req to underline email id in the message. Is there existing method in RTF to achieve it els what is the way?

`RichTextBox _RichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
_RichTextBox.Find("Important Notice");
_RichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;`

and also i would like to add an information icon `i` front of my message. could you please guide for this both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821347/how-to-selectively-underline-strings-in-richtextbox

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask them separately.