# Different style format in a single string value

Tags: c#, windows, string, ms-word

How to have multiple font style in a single string.

I have a big string and i will append that string to a microsoft word from c# windows application.

I want some characters to be bold... some with big font. like that.

I tried with ordinary HTML tags like < b > bold ..< / b> it wont work..

I want string with mixed font styles.

```
  Text  BOLD  small BIG
```

I am Exporting that string to a word file from c# windows application as i mentioned.

Help Much appreciated.

Comment: Please supply some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

the keyword of your question is **RTF, RichText format string** see

- [Better Way of Manipulating RichText in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136132/better-way-of-manipulating-richtext-in-c)

  - [How to convert a string to RTF in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795709/how-to-convert-a-string-to-rtf-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RTF - see ["How to paste a Rich Text Format string into Word with Visual Basic Automation"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258513) for an example (in VB.Net, but it would work the same in C#)

Comment: Thanks This is what i want. will do that in c#.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no style for a string**. A string is a list of characters, that's all.

If you want to copy/paste a styled **text** to word, you'll have to export it in another format first. You could use HTML or RTF.

[This lib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C) might help you.